# How to Convert a Typescript Enum into another Enum with the same key?

Tags: typescript, enums, type-conversion

I have two very similar TypeScript enums that I want to convert between.

```
export enum WeekDay {
    MONDAY = "MONDAY",
    TUESDAY = "TUESDAY",
    WEDNESDAY = "WEDNESDAY",
    THURSDAY = "THURSDAY",
    FRIDAY = "FRIDAY",
    SATURDAY = "SATURDAY",
    SUNDAY = "SUNDAY"
}
```

```
export enum SpecialWeekDay {
    MONDAY = "Moon's Day",
    TUESDAY = "Tyr's Day",
    WEDNESDAY = "Odin's Day",
    THURSDAY = "Thor's Day",
    FRIDAY = "Freya's Day",
    SATURDAY = "Saturn's Day",
    SUNDAY = "Sun's Day"
}
```

In the past I have converted using the following:

```
let value: SpecialWeekDay = SpecialWeekDay.MONDAY;
let newValue: WeekDay = WeekDay[SpecialWeekDay[value] as keyof typeof WeekDay];
```

But it's not working for me, it seems that the value is being compared and not the keys. Is there a simple way to achieve this? I would rather not manually create a mapping because this happens quite often in my project and I need to go both ways.

Comment: Are you okay with converting it to an object? Because I don't think it's possible with enums, since you can't use the value interchangeably for string enums.

Comment: Numeric enums [come with reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) automatically, but string enums don't.  You need to reverse your string enum yourself but you could do it programmatically; see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wyxndm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?